# How do I convert these global variables into local variables?

Tags: c

I'm making a bus seat reservation system for my project and I've coded a lot of it now but I realized upon reading my project requirements, global variables are not allowed. I'm stuck with this code because I don't know how I can convert these variables to local ones cause I'm going to be switching between different functions back and forth.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char name[20], embarkationpoint[20], tripnumber[4];
int idnumber, prioritynumber, dropoff;

FILE *fptr;
char filename[40];
struct tm *timenow;
time_t now;

void enlistment(); //Get user input
void busReservation(); //
void trips();

int main()
{
    enlistment();
    return 0;
}

void enlistment()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter Embarkation Point (Manila or Laguna): \n");
        scanf("%s", embarkationpoint);
        if (strcmp(embarkationpoint, "Manila") == 0 || strcmp(embarkationpoint, "manila") == 0)
        {
            printf("You selected Manila!\n");
        }
        else if (strcmp(embarkationpoint, "Laguna") == 0 || strcmp(embarkationpoint, "laguna") == 0)
        {
            printf("You selected Laguna!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input! Try again.\n");

        }
    }
    while (strcmp(embarkationpoint, "Manila") != 0 && strcmp(embarkationpoint, "manila") != 0 && strcmp(embarkationpoint, "Laguna") != 0 && strcmp(embarkationpoint, "laguna") != 0);
    
    sleep(1);
    system("CLS"); 

    do
    {
        printf("======================================================= Priority Group Numbers ===============================================================\n");
        printf("1. Faculty and ASF with Inter-campus assignments\n");
        printf("2. Students with Inter-campus enrolled subjects or enrolled in thesis using Inter-campus facilities\n");
        printf("3. Researchers\n");
        printf("4. School Administrators (Academic Coordinators level and up for Faculty and ASF, and Director level and up for APSP)\n");
        printf("5. University Fellows\n");
        printf("6. Employees and Students with official business\n");
        printf("==============================================================================================================================================\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter your priority group number: \n");
        scanf("%i", &prioritynumber);
        if (prioritynumber == 1)
        {
            printf("You are a faculty or an ASF with inter-campus assignments!\n");
        }
        else if (prioritynumber == 2)
        {   
            printf("You are a student with inter-campus enrolled subjects or enrolled in thesis using inter-campus facilities!\n");
        }
        else if (prioritynumber == 3)
        {
            printf("You are a researcher!\n");
        }
        else if (prioritynumber == 4)
        {
            printf("You are a school administrator (Academic Coordinators level and up for Faculty and ASF, and Director level and up for APSP)!\n");
        }
        else if (prioritynumber == 5)
        {
            printf("You are a university fellow!\n");
        }
        else if (prioritynumber == 6)
        {
            printf("You are an employee or student with official business!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input! Try again.\n");
            printf("%i", prioritynumber);
        }
    }
    while (prioritynumber != 1 && prioritynumber != 2 && prioritynumber != 3 && prioritynumber != 4 && prioritynumber != 5 && prioritynumber != 6);

    sleep(1);
    system("CLS");

    trips();
    busReservation();

    
    printf("\nEnter Name: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("\nEnter ID Number: \n");
    scanf("%i", &idnumber);
    printf("\nEnter Drop-off Point: \n");
    scanf("%i", &dropoff);

    struct tm *timenow;
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    timenow = gmtime(&now);
    strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "Trip-%d-%m-%Y", timenow);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");
    
    fptr = fopen(filename, "a");

    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", tripnumber);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", embarkationpoint);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", name);
    fprintf(fptr, "%i\n", idnumber);
    fprintf(fptr, "%i\n", prioritynumber);
    fprintf(fptr, "%i\n\n", dropoff);

    fclose(fptr);

}

void trips()
{
    if (strcmp(embarkationpoint, "Manila") == 0 || strcmp(embarkationpoint, "manila") == 0)
    {
        printf("=== Trip Numbers =============================== ETD =====================\n");
        printf("       AE101                                   6:00 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE102                                   7:30 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE103                                   9:30 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE104                                  11:00 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE105                                   1:00 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE106                                   2:30 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE107                                   3:30 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE108                                   5:00 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE109                                   6:15 PM    \n");
        printf("=========================== Manila to Laguna =============================\n");

        do
        {
            printf("Enter Trip Number: \n");
            scanf("%s", &tripnumber);
            if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE101") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE102") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE103") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE104") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE105") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE106") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE107") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE108") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE109") != 0)
            {
                printf("Invalid input! Try again.\n\n");
            }
        } 
        while (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE101") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE102") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE103") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE104") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE105") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE106") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE107") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE108") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE109") != 0);
        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("=== Trip Numbers =============================== ETD =====================\n");
        printf("       AE150                                   5:30 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE151                                   5:45 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE152                                   7:00 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE153                                   7:30 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE154                                   9:00 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE155                                  11:00 AM    \n");
        printf("       AE156                                   1:00 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE157                                   2:30 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE158                                   3:30 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE159                                   5:00 PM    \n");
        printf("       AE160                                   6:15 PM    \n");
        printf("=========================== Laguna to Manila =============================\n");

        do
        {
            printf("Enter Trip Number: \n");
            scanf("%s", &tripnumber);
            if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE150") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE151") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE152") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE153") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE154") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE155") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE156") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE157") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE158") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE159") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE160") != 0)
            {
                printf("Invalid input! Try again.\n\n");
            }
        } 
        while (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE150") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE151") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE152") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE153") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE154") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE155") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE156") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE157") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE158") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE159") != 0 && strcmp(tripnumber, "AE160") != 0);
    }
}

void busReservation()
{
    //ask/get trip number
    //display how many passengers are on board
    //display the array diagram thing showing x for taken seats and o for open seats
    
    if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE101") == 0)
    {
        struct tm *timenow;
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        timenow = gmtime(&now);
        strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "Trip-%d-%m-%Y", timenow);
        strcat(filename, ".txt");

        fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
        
        char string[50];
        int num=0;
        while (fscanf(fptr,"%s", string) == 1)
            {
                if(strstr(string, tripnumber)!=0) 
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }
        printf("%s has %d out of 13 passengers\n", tripnumber, num);

        if(num == 13)
        {
            printf("Trip is full! Please book another trip.\n");
            trips();
        }

        num = 0;
    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE102") == 0)
    {
        
    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE103") == 0)
    {
        
    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE104") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE105") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE106") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE107") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE108") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE109") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE150") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE151") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE152") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE153") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE154") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE155") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE156") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE157") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE158") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE159") == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (strcmp(tripnumber, "AE160") == 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. You can put those variables in a struct. Create struct object in a main function. Pass this object abound you other functions, as an argument.

Comment: @user14063792468 can you give me an example? sorry, i'm pretty new to this and i can't understand the references posted online

Comment: What references?

Comment: i'm reading on passing struct by reference on programiz and other sites and I can't quite understand it enough to apply to my program

Comment: That's a mighty set of `if`s you have there in `busReservation`. if you put all the values in an array, you could loop over them all and only have _one_ `if`.

Comment: `C` language does not have a reference type.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about material covered in an elementary C course that should be resolved by reading course materials and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In C you pass by reference by passing pointers. So if you have a struct in the variable `mydata`, you call a function `func(&mydata)`. Then the function can dereference the pointer to access and modify the structure data.

Answer (score 2):

**One** way of doing this, would have be:

```
struct bus_trip {
 /* your variables here */
};

int reserve_trip(struct bus_trip *parg){
 /* ... */
 /* use your record */
 scanf("%s", parg->name);
 return 0;
}

int main(){

 struct bus_trip trip = {
  .idnumber = /* your default, or comuted id */
  /* rest of the defualts */
 };

 reserve_trip(&trip); /* get an address of a variable */
 /* rest of your code */
}
```